# Parsing C/C++ source: How are token boundaries/interactions specified in lex/yacc?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, yacc, bison

I want to parse some C++ code, and as a guide I've been looking at the C lex/yacc definitions here: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html and http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html

I understand the specifications of the tokens themselves, but not how they interact.  eg. it's OK to have an operator such as = directly follow an identifier without intervening white space (ie. "foo="), but it's not OK to have a numerical constant immediately followed by an identifier (ie. 123foo).  However, I don't see any way that such rules are represented.

What am I missing?... or is this lex/yacc too liberal in its acceptance of errors.

Comment: You had me at "I want to parse some C++ code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lexer converts a character stream into a token stream (I think that's what you mean by token specification). The grammar specifies what sequences of tokens are acceptable. Hence, you won't see that something is not allowed; you only see what is allowed. Does that make sense?

**EDIT**

If the point is to get the lexer to distinguish the sequence "123foo" from the sequence "123 foo" one way is to add a specification for "123foo". Another way is to treat spaces as significant.

**EDIT2**

A syntax error can be "detected" from the lexer or the grammar production or the later stages of the compiler (think of, say, type errors, which are still "syntax errors"). Which part of the whole compilation process detects which error is largely a design issue (as it affects the quality of error messages), I think. In the given example, it probably makes more sense to outlaw "123foo" via a tokenization to an invalid token rather than relying on the non-existence of a production with a numeric literal followed by an identifier (at least, this is the behaviour of gcc).

Comment: Ah, so your saying it's not that "123foo" is directly disallowed, but rather that even "123 foo" isn't legal, yes?

Comment: I think i'm abit confused by your question. "123foo" probably doesn't even lex as a single token (there is no expression in the lex specification that accepts 123foo).

Comment: but the idea is that the acceptable is specified, and everything that doesn't match the specification is unacceptable.

Comment: Exactly, 123foo would (i think) be lexed as two seperate tokens, 123 and foo.  That was my point, how does it "know" that "123" followed by "foo" is valid when there is intervening whitespace but not without.  But I understand that it's not the lexer that knows this but rather the grammar.

Comment: with the linked lex specification, i believe "123foo" and "123 foo" lex to the same sequence of tokens. (a CONSTANT followed by a IDENTIFIER).

Comment: oh! is your question: how does one get the lexer to reject 123foo but accept 123 foo?

Comment: yeah, i'd be interested to know that as a follow up :-)

Comment: @Greencpp: Why would you want it to reject 123foo at the lexer stage?

Comment: I don't necessarily... just trying to get my head around it all.  This discussion has helped.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The lexer is fine with 123foo and will split that into two tokens.

- An integer constant
- and an identifier.

But try and find the part in the syntax that allows those two tokens to sit side by side like that. Thus I bet the lexer is generating an error when it sees these two tokens.

Note the lexer does not care about whitespace (unless you explicitly tell it tow worry). In this case it just throws white space away:

```
[ \t\v\n\f]     { count(); } // Throw away white space without looking.
```

Just to check this is what I built:

```
wget http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html > l.l
wget http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html > y.y
```

Edited file l.l to stop in the compiler complaining about undeclared functions:

```
#include "y.tab.h"

// Add the following lines
int  yywrap();
void count();
void comment();
void count();
int  check_type();
// Done adding lines

%}
```

Create the following file: main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int yylex();

int main()
{
    int x;
    while((x = yylex()) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Token(%d)\n", x);
    }
}
```

Build it:

```
$ bison -d y.y
y.y: conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
$ flex l.l
$ gcc main.c lex.yy.c
$ ./a.out
123foo
123Token(259)
fooToken(258)
```

Yes it split it into two tokens.

Comment: Right, i was getting hung up on the presence of whitespace, but it's invalid regardless.

Comment: the part generated by lex won't complain if the tokens don't go together in the grammer; the part generated by yacc will.

Comment: @Greencpp: What's invalid. Its a perfectly valid token stream (as the lexer does not care about syntax). But it is a syntax error and thus the parser should complain.

Answer (score 0):

what's essentially going on is the lexical rules for each token type are greedy.  For instance, the character sequence `foo=` cannot be interpreted as a single identifier, because identifiers don't contain symbols.  on the other hand, `123abc` is actually a numerical constant, though malformed, because numerical constants can end with a sequence of alphabetic characters that are used to express the type of the numerical constant.

Comment: strictly speaking, `123abc` is invalid c++03, but valid c++0x, because c++0x has a User Defined Literal feature (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#User-defined_literals)

Comment: I thought that only limited alphas are allowed after the digits, ie. [uUlL]... are you saying that the spec is more general than that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the linked-to lex specification would actually tokenize `123foo` as a constant followed by an identifier, not as a single (malformed) constant.

Comment: suppose, in c++03, i had a source sequence like `123ublabla`, this could be interpreted ambigiously as the literal `123` followed by an identifier `ublabla`, which would likely be what was meant, but since the lexer is greedy, it would be interpreted as `123u` and `blabla`.  It's basically impossible to make a case that this is good, so literals may end in an identifier-like sequence, and are validated/evaluated as a separate step.

Comment: I think it is a ?deliberate? choice whether or not to perform greedy matching in the lexer (just that most languages *do* match greedily).

Comment: And it seems that seperate step is the grammar, yes? ie. "CONSTANT IDENTIFIER" is not valid, so regardless of presence/absense of whitespace between 123 and foo, the construct if invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to parse C++ with lex and yacc, as it's an ambiguous grammar. You'd need a more powerful approach such as GLR or some hackish solution which modifies a lexer in runtime (that's what most of the current C++ parsers are doing).

Take a look at Elsa/Elkhound.

Comment: Bison supports GLR now, so it would be suitable for parsing C++.

Comment: Don't confuse the ability to do "raw parsing" with making progress on processing real C++ code.  You also need name and type resolution and lots of other stuff.  And the C++14 standard is out; it is *ginormous"; good luck taking all that into account as part of putting your tool together.  (My company offer a full C++11 nearly C++14 parser and so can be accused of being biased; just note that my company has been developing this for over a decade.)

Comment: @IraBaxter, by the time of this answer Elsa could be considered a pretty complete C++ parser and semantic analyser implementation. Not any more, of course. Unfortunately it was not maintained since then. Nevertheless, now, with Clang being available and complete, there is little to no need in such tools.